# Merging two data frames horizontally by ID and keep only matches from the second one

Tags: r, join, semi-join

I have two data frames which I want to merge horizontally:

```
dat_a

  a b c
1 1 1 A
2 2 1 A
3 3 1 B
4 4 1 B


dat_b

  a b c
1 3 1 C
2 3 1 C
3 3 1 D
4 4 1 D
```

I want to only keep those rows from `dat_a` which have a match in `dat_b` for columns `a` and `b`.

So the final result should look like this:

```
dat_c
   a b c
1 3 1 B
2 4 1 B
3 3 1 C
4 3 1 C
5 3 1 D
6 4 1 D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `semi_join` from the `dplyr` package.

If you want only the rows `dat_a` which have a match in `dat_b` you can use:

```
library(dplyr)
dat_a %>% semi_join(dat_b, by = c("a", "b"))
```

If - like in your desired output - you want all columns of `dat_a` which have a match in `dat_b` and all columns in `dat_b` which habe match in `dat_a`try:

```
dat_a %>% semi_join(dat_b, by = c("a", "b")) 
  %>% bind_rows(dat_b %>% semi_joim(dat_a, by = c("a", "b")))
```